# How to empty and delete an array with a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

## Problem

1. I can't empty an array with the `s` parameter
2. I can't `delete` an array with the `deleteThis` parameter

```js
sentences = {
  all: [
    //1,000s of Sentences
    "This sentence meets all conditions.",
    "This sentence meets all conditions.",
    "This sentence failed.",
    "This sentence failed.",
    "This sentence meets all conditions.",
    "This sentence failed."
  ],
  success: [],
  failed: [],
  moveTo_then_Delete: []
}




function Divide_And_Empty(s, success, failed, deleteThis, regEx) {
  s.filter(function(str) {
    key = regEx.test(str)
    if (key) {
      success.push(str)
    } else {
      failed.push(str)
      deleteThis.push(str)
    }
  });

  //The code works correctly
  //All the way up until I try to empty and/or delete an array with parameter
  s = []
  delete deleteThis
}
Divide_And_Empty(sentences.all, sentences.success, sentences.failed, sentences.moveTo_then_Delete, /meets/)



document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(sentences, null, 2) + "</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is `Divide_And_Conquer` ?

Comment: Sorry… It's updated… I was typing the question out to fast and didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `s` refers to the array that you pass in the arguments. You can only mutate this array.

If you want to remove all elements from array named `s`, then you should use

`s.length = 0;`

or

`s.splice(0, s.length)` 
instead of `s = []`:

```js
sentences = {
  all: [
    //1,000s of Sentences
    "This sentence meets all conditions.",
    "This sentence meets all conditions.",
    "This sentence failed.",
    "This sentence failed.",
    "This sentence meets all conditions.",
    "This sentence failed."
  ],
  success: [],
  failed: [],
}

function Divide_And_Empty(s, success, failed, regEx) {
  s.filter(function(str) {
    key = regEx.test(str)
    if (key) {
      success.push(str)
    } else {
      failed.push(str)
    }
  });

  s.length = 0; // or s.splice(0, s.length);
}

Divide_And_Empty(sentences.all, sentences.success, sentences.failed, /meets/);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(sentences, null, 2) + "</pre>");
```